# Basic Function Producing Infinite Loop

Tags: c, loops, infinite

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) 
{
    double x, y, z;
    double numerator;
    double denominator;
    printf("This program will solve (x^2+y^2)/(x/y)^3\n");
    printf("Enter the value for x:\n");
    scanf("%lf", x);
    printf("Enter the value for y:\n");
    scanf("%lf", y);
    numerator = sqrt(x) + sqrt(y);
    denominator = pow((x/y),3);
    z = (numerator/denominator);
    printf("The solution is: %f\n", z);
    return(0);

}
```

Can anyone give me a (hopefully) quick pointer to fix my infinite loop?

Comment: You should read in the variables via `scanf("%lf", &x);`. scanf will modify the value of the variables in your program, thus you always need to pass a reference to the variable in your function.

Comment: `sqrt(x)` returns square root, not square. Use `pow(x,2)`.

Comment: There are no infinite loops in the code. If you have problems handling the *input*, say so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no loop in your function, so I think it's your calls to `scanf()` that are causing the error:

You need to pass reference to `scanf()`, i.e. use `scanf("%lf",&x)` instead of `scanf("%lf",x)`.

BTW, according to your fonction definition, you should use `pow(x,2)` instead of `sqrt(x)` which returns the square root.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your first question

```
**Welcome to stack overflow**
```

Your code doesnt go into an infinite loop,there is a runtime error.
Your scanf Code is flawed use this:

```
scanf("%lf",&x); 
scanf("%lf",&y);
```

you want scanf to modify the value contained at the address field of your value.Please read tutorials.

Also use

```
numerator=pow(x,2) + pow(y,2);//numerator=x^2+y^2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not infinite loop, your code just returns infinity. And that is because scanf() needs a pointer to variable where it should put the read number. To get an address of variable you can use `&` operator like this:

```
scanf("%lf", &x);
scanf("%lf", &y);
```